# Prove that $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C} \exists c,d \in \mathbb{C}: c+d = a \land cd = b$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, complex-numbers, field-theory

> Prove that: $\forall a,b\in\mathbb{C} \exists c,d \in \mathbb{C}: c+d = a \land cd = b$

We just learned about the characteristic/minimal polynomial and diagonalization but I am not sure if it has something to do with this question.

I'd be glad for guidance!

Comment: It has something to do with Vieta's formulas and the fact that $\mathbb{C}$ is algebraically closed field.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider the polynomial $X^2-aX+b \in \mathbb{C}[X]$. It has two roots ...

Comment: Thank you. How did you think about it?